# Can we get HTTP status code 429 with html also in response

Tags: http, nutch, selenium-grid, http-status-code-429

I am using Apache Nutch 1.14 with protocol selenium. The setting in `nutch-site.xml` for this is

```
<property>
  <name>plugin.includes</name>
  <value>protocol-selenium|urlfilter-(regex|validator)|parse-(html|tika)|index-(basic|anchor)|indexer-solr|scoring-opic|urlnormalizer-(pass|regex|basic)</value>
  <!--<value>protocol-http|protocol-httpclient|urlfilter-(regex|validator)|parse-(html|tika)|index-(basic|anchor)|indexer-solr|scoring-opic|urlnormalizer-(pass|regex|basic)</value>-->
  <description>Regular expression naming plugin directory names to ...  
  </description>
</property>
```

I am trying to crawl a site. I am using selenium Hub and Node.

I am getting Http Status Code 429.
But I am able to see the html page on the browser also.
But Nutch not creating directory for `raw_html`

I am getting this error

> failed with: Http code=429, url=https://www.expedia.com/

also there is no error in `hadoop log` file

Comment: The HTTP status code 429 means "Too Many Requests", it's likely the Selenium hub/nodes/grid responded with this code. What does the Selenium logs tell?

Comment: @SebastianNagel Not error in log.